# IOS build getting failed with build hint codename1.arg.ios.xcode_version=7.3

Tags: codenameone

Today IOS debug build is getting failed with build hint codename1.arg.ios.xcode_version=7.3 for older OS iOS devices. Anyone facing same issue?

Please see the log:

```
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.o Main-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Main-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -include /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/PrecompiledHeaders/Main-Prefix-gzksruskubtjxyfxgejmlrxqjuuz/Main-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.dia -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Main.build/Release-iphoneos/Main.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.o
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m:23:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7379057061865143274xxx/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.h:26:9: fatal error: 'UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h' file not found
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly target xcode 7.3 that could lead to regressions.

You should remove the xcode 7.3 target and leave the default (9.2). We are integrating support for new push notification features and are adopting features of xcode 9.

Comment: If I want to do a debug build for older devices, without xcode 7.3 build hint App is not working. I have to add the hint and do a separate debug build. Please advise if any work around?

Comment: I'm assuming it's failing because of signing when you remove that hint right? In that case you need to regenerate the certificate. The new certificate wizard update generates certificates that work with xcode 9.x.